# why in Symfony $this->tokenStorage->getToken(); returns null in prod?

Tags: php, symfony

i tried to figure out why my user in dev is logged in and in prod not. Its the same code in dev like in prod and i have no idea why i get no user in prod.

my authentication looks like this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
//dd($this->tokenStorage->getToken()); returns my user in dev and prod
$this->session->set('_security_main', serialize($jwt));
```

after this i have a method checkIfUserLoggedIn():

```
$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken(); //returns user in dev and null in prod
$user = null;
if(null == $token)
{
   //...
}
```

Do you have any idea whats wrong in here or where i can take to look to find out more about this?

The Regularly Login doesnt work too in prod, but this is a bug in csrf and prod. csrf invalid.

Comment: Why do you want to manually authenticate the user? Click here for more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#form-login

Comment: its an api login where json data is sent from apps

Comment: check out CustomAuthenticator. In the code example is the case of API Token authentification. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html

Comment: Ok, i'll try, but it doesnt explain why this error is only in prod. Let u know about the custom authenticator

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have never worked with JWT before. Maybe the serialization is not fully checked in dev, but in prod it is?

Comment: the jwt is working in both. when i sent this header im authenticated, no problem. But this auth ist stateless and i want a real auth. Buth the idea with custom authenticator isnt the worst. ;)

Comment: Maybe it helps
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22513

Comment: Thx a lot, maybe this could be my problem. i'll check this out.